# Get Child Input Data-Attr of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a code with something like this:

```
<div class='radio_btn checked'>
<input type='text' class='searchfield' data-inputtype='somthing'></input>
</div>
```

In jQ, I need to get this value of data-input if the radio_btn is checked. How do I do that? I've already tried something like `var elem = $('.checked').find('.searchfiled')` and `$(elem).data('inputtype')`. But I always get undefined and I've tried other ways I know, still nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I need to get this value of data-input if the radio_btn is checked."_ `<div>` element does not have a `.checked` property.

Comment: `.attr('data-inputtype')`

Comment: @guest271314 look closely, it has a class checked

Comment: @madalinivascu Does OP mean if `"radio_btn"` element has `.className` `"checked"`?

Comment: @guest271314 i think so because he hasn't got a radio buton

Comment: @madalinivascu There are no `<input type="button">` or `<button>` elements at `html` at Question.

Comment: @JDoeBloke How does element having `.className` `"radio_btn"` get  `.className` `"checked"` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your trying to get the attribute of the searchfield using the parent div .. you can use this

```
$('.checked').children('.searchfield').attr('data-inputtype');
```

or

```
var elem = $('.checked').children('.searchfield');
$(elem).data('inputtype');
```